# how to change background of div (like progress bar) when user finished inputting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to change background of div when user fill all the input in a part of form. Is there any way I can get it done but to place a button in it and click that button to change the background

```css
.step-dots div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="">Apple</label>
                <input type="text" id="" name="text-group" checked>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="">Apple</label>
                <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="">Apple</label>
                <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="">Apple</label>
                <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
<div class="step-dots">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using jquery in your project?

Comment: Yes I'm using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `blur` event , check input value and based upon that add / remove your div class.

```js
$("input").blur(function() {
  let Counter = true;
  $('[name="text-group"]').each(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
      Counter = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (Counter) {
    $('.step-dots div').addClass('divColor');
  } else {
    $('.step-dots div').removeClass('divColor');
  }

});
```

```css
.step-dots div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.divColor {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label for="">Apple</label>
      <input type="text" id="" name="text-group" checked>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label for="">Apple</label>
      <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label for="">Apple</label>
      <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label for="">Apple</label>
      <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="step-dots">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Alternative:

You can also use [keup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead of [blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/). Choice is yours and it's depend upon your need.

Answer (score 1):

You have to append step dots as amount of input fields in form.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 // Loop through each Input field
 $('input[type="text"]').each(function(index, el) {

  // If Input field don't have ID, assign Input Index number as a ID of it's Step dot
  if ($(this).attr('id') == '') {
   $(this).attr('id', index);

   // Add step dots dynamically as amount of Input fields
   $(this).parents('form').siblings('.step-dots').append('<div data-target='+index+'></div>');
  }

  // If Input field have ID, assign Input ID as a ID of it's Step dot
  else{

   // Add step dots dynamically as amount of Input fields
   $(this).parents('form').siblings('.step-dots').append('<div data-target='+$(this).attr('id')+'></div>');
  }
 });

 // Check Input field value then change background color if any value in it
 $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // If input field is not blank, step dot has background color 
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
   $('.step-dots').find('[data-target="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').css('background', 'red');
  }

  // If input field is blank, step dot hasn't background color
  else{
   $('.step-dots').find('[data-target="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').removeAttr('style');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.step-dots div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 7px;
 height: 7px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background: #d9d9d9;
 margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <label for="">Apple</label>
   <input type="text" id="" name="text-group" checked>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <label for="">Apple</label>
   <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <label for="">Apple</label>
   <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <label for="">Apple</label>
   <input type="text" id="" name="text-group">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<div class="step-dots">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkFilled() {
 var inputVal = document.getElementById("textinput");
    if (inputVal.value == "") {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else{
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}
 
checkFilled();
```

```css
.step-dots div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="">Apple</label>
                <input type="text" id="textinput" name="text-group" onchange="checkFilled();">
            </div>
         </div>
</form>
<div class="step-dots">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
</div>
```